# When I create a view using xml layout in cakephp, a head tag is showed

Tags: php, xml, cakephp

I'm using Cake PHP 2.0, and when I created a xml view using the XML layout a  is showed.

My controller is:

```
<?php
class SiteMapController extends AppController {

    function beforeFilter(){
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allowedActions = array_merge( $this->Auth->allowedActions,
                array( 'map' ) );

        if ($this->RequestHandler->isXml())
            $this->RequestHandler->setContent('xml');
    }

    public function map(){

        $this->loadModel('SiteMap');
        $data = $this->SiteMap->google();

        $this->set(compact('data'));
        $this->set('_serialize',array('data'));
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

My view is:

```
<?php
$this->layout = 'xml/default';
$array = array();
$result = '';
foreach ( $data as &$value ) {
    $aux = $value[ 0 ];
    $loc = $this->Html->url( $aux[ 'loc' ], true );
    if( $aux['title'] )
        $loc .= '/' . $this->Common->textToUrl( $aux['title'] );

    $changefreq = $aux[ 'changefreq' ];
    $priority = $aux[ 'priority' ];
    $lastmod = $aux[ 'lastmod' ];

    $xml = "<loc>$loc</loc><changefreq>$changefreq</changefreq><priority>$priority</priority>";
    if( $lastmod )
        $xml .= "<lastmod>$lastmod</lastmod>";

    $result .= "<url>$xml</url>"; 
}

echo "<urlset xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\">$result</urlset>";
?>
```

The result is:

```
<head/><urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"><url><loc>http://test.tocadealuguel.com.br/users/new_user</loc><changefreq>monthly</changefreq><priority>0.90</priority></url><url><loc>http://test.tocadealuguel.com.br/</loc><changefreq>monthly</changefreq><priority>0.80</priority></url></urlset>
```

In the first line of the result, a head tag "" appear, and I don't kokw the why and I have no a idea to remove it.

Could you help me please?

Comment: try $this->layout = 'ajax'; or add your  'xml/default.ctp'; code to question.

Comment: I tried it. But it's work just in the dev environment. In the serve it didn't work.